# Excel add-in with service reference in class library fails to connect

Tags: .net, wcf, excel, installation, class-library

I have created an Excel 2010 VSTO Add-in in visual studio (c#). The add-in uses a class library that has a service reference to a wcf service. The same wcf-service is also referenced in the add-in project. There is also a setup project that I created using this whitepaper http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx

This works fine when I am debugging. Excel launches and I am able to step through the code and call the wcf-service. The setup also seems to work as intended, the add-in gets registred in excel and all the functions that does not need the wcf-service are working.

However, when trying to use the functions that require the wcf-service I get the following error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'PurchOrder.POrderService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Since I have the same service reference in the add-in project the app-config contains the endpoint configurations. When I look at the files created by the installer the dll.config file contains these endpoint configurations aswell.

I have googled as much as I can about this and there are several similar problems posted but I can't seem to find a solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Update: I tried installing the add-in manually from the vsto-file. This works fine so the problem must be with the setup project.